# jQuery UI DatePicker not working on plugin admin page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

My first StackOverflow question - apologies if there are mistakes. I know there are lots of existing questions about registering/using the datepicker in a plugin but none of them solves my problem.

Here's the code in my child theme's functions.php

```
// load jQuery date picker for public and admin pages
function wp_sos_enqueue_front_datepicker() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}
function wp_sos_enqueue_back_datepicker() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_sos_enqueue_back_datepicker' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_sos_enqueue_front_datepicker' );
```

In my front-end form I have this html:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="sstxtdate"/>
```

and in the js I have this:

```
jQuery('#sstxtdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

The above works.

In my admin page form I have this html:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="2017-07-09" id="txtrsdate"/>
```

and when I execute this js

```
jQuery('#txtrsdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

I get this error on the Console

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (recent-sightings-admin.js?ver=1.0.0:78)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.8.1:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.8.1:2)
    at y (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.8.1:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.8.1:4)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

I've solved this problem. Here's how, in case it helps anybody else.

On the same page that contains the date picker control I also need an instance of the WP Editor which I created using the following code (found elsewhere in Stack Overflow)

```
wp_editor( $row["description"], 'tasighting', $settings );
\_WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts();
print_footer_scripts();
\_WP_Editors::editor_js();
```

If I remove the _WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts(); line then the Date picker works fine. Presumably a script conflict of some kind?

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI? All I see from above is the CSS, not the JavaScript. `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function` indicates to me that you're not.

Comment: @j08691 Do you mean add a wp_enqueue_script for 'jquery-ui' as well? I've added that to my functions.php code and it makes no difference.

Comment: According to the error, jQuery UI isn't being loaded, or at least if it is, it's not loaded with the datepicker widget.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry if I'm being dumb - How would I do that (given that it presumably is being loaded for the front-end page)?